Remove orphaned docker network interfaces from Landscape
$lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble
The Nextcloud AIO docker image backups at midnight and creates new docker network interfaces, e.g., veth30869f3. Even though the orphaned interfaces are removed on the server itself, they are still present on the Landscape network monitoring section in an ever-increasing list of unused interfaces. How can I remove these? I fear the page will grow to infinity.Landscape Network Monitoring

please read [ask] then [edit] accordingly - specifically mentioning which Linux distro/version you are using.

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What version of Ubuntu are you running? Please run lsb_release -a and Edit your question to include this information.

Sorry about this, it's fixed now. :)

Bump. No answers to this?
